# People Picker Field Validation without Designer

Tags: 2010, jquery, form

SharePoint 2010 and unable to use SharePoint Designer

**Form:**

Users answer a yes/no question in one column, then provide a name in another column. The people picker column is only required when the previous column is 'Yes'.

**Failure Mode:**

If a user selects 'Yes', the people picker column can be left blank and no one is notified.

**Want:**

To add column validation so that if 'Yes' is selected and there is no information in the people picker column, the user cannot save the form and notifies the user why.

**Progress:**

So far I am planning on adding a content editor webpart to form entry with a script. The problem is I cannot get the script to function (I only know what I can google)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this [SHOW / HIDE FIELDS BASED ON CHOICE FIELD SELECTION USING JQUERY IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/).

A section of the code:

```
if ($("select[title='City']").val() != "other")
{
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else {
$('nobr:contains("OtherCity")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').show();}
```

Result 1:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called PreSaveAction() in sharepoint that your can override. It will execute after the save button is clicked and only complete the save if you return true.

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    var flag = true;

    if(!condition){
      //validation failed
      //highlight a field red or do an alert
      flag = false;
    }

    return flag;

 }
```

You can try to link something like. The only problem is I am not sure about the load order of this script if you try to link it in a webpart. Its worth a shot though, it is how custom form validation is intended to be used in SharePoint.